# Select all ids from a MySql table by a user level and store the number of ids per level in an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following function :

```
//Counts The Users In The Database Per Level And Stores The Results In An Array
public function countUsers() {
    $users = array();
    $length = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i >= 2; $i++){
        $sql   = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_level = '$i'";
        if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
            $stmt->bind_result($id);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                $stmt->bind_result($id);
                $users[] = $id;
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $length[] = sizeof($users);
        } else {
            $error              = true;
            $message['error']   = true;
            $message['message'] = CANNOT_PREPARE_DATABASE_CONNECTION_MESSAGE;
            return json_encode($message);
        }
    }   
    return $length;
}
```

This function is suppose to loop through the table and store the id's in an array for each level and then get the sizeof each array per level. I mean, I have 10 user for level 0, 23 for level 1 and so on, and I need this info stored in an array.

What is wrong with my function ?

Comment: `for( $i = 0; $i >= 2; $i++){` interesting..

Comment: For one, that FOR loop will run forever. Actually, it will never run...

Comment: No, that for loop will run never.

Comment: Yeah, didn't see it was initialized at 0 at first :-p

Comment: Oh, yeah, the condition `$i >= 2` should have been `$i <= 2`. Anyway I tried I just got an empty array.

Comment: @dfsq - It was a stupid mistake, but even though it was the other way around, it didn't work. As @boro suggested, `$users` should have been inside the for loop, which did the trick.

Comment: @BD.suggested proper solution. You should use it.

Comment: OK, and how would I output the counts into a php variable ?

Comment: You can use fetchall to get an array of the results: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you have the SQL do more of the work for you?

```
SELECT   user_level,COUNT(user_id) usercount
FROM     users 
GROUP BY user_level;
```

That will give you all the counts for each user level.

Comment: OK, and how would I output that counts into php ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$users = array();
```

Should be in the for loop.
But will be much better if you change your sql query to:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_level = '$i'"
```

or will be even better if you use GROUP BY clause

Comment: Yes, placing the `$users` variable inside the for did the trick.